# Automatically convert dates based on time zone

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

**Objective:**

Knowing that my main column dates is in UTC time but is taking data from the Time zone 'Dateline Standard Time', how can I ensure that my query accounts for the offset without having to manually do `DATEADD(HOUR,-8,column_name)`. This is especially important for day light savings periods.

```
select
    , created_at 
    , created_at at time zone 'Dateline Standard Time' as dates_zone
```

**The output of this is:**

```
created_at                 created_at_timezone
2019-07-01 00:45:04.000    2019-07-01 00:45:04.000 -12:00
```

**but I'd rather have the end result as such:**
(which is basically UTC-8)

```
created_at_modified            
2019-06-30 16:45:04.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to `datetimeoffset`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset,created_at) AT TIME ZONE 'Dateline Standard Time' created_at_modified
FROM …
;
```

Comment: the issue i have is that the raw dates  is GMT-12:00 International Date Line West. On the database, its -8:00 . Your formula reduces it by 12 hours instead of 8. (My dates on the database are UTC which is why its causing an 8 hour discrepancy